# Importing .dae file on Processing

Tags: object, animation, processing, blender, collada

What I am trying to do is export from Blender a .dae file of an animated object and then import this file on processing and use it there. I created a rotating cube, baked action and exported it as .dae file. the problem is when I am importing it on processing the animation doesn't work and I can see only a square.

```
import ch.dieseite.colladaloader.ColladaLoader;
import ch.dieseite.colladaloader.wrappers.ColladaModel;

ColladaModel model;

void setup() {
  size(500,600,P3D);
  background(255);
  lights();
  frameRate(10);
  model = ColladaLoader.load("cuberot.dae", this, null);
  model.scale(25);
}

void draw() {
  translate(width/2,height/2);
  model.draw(); 
}
```

Can someone explain how this can work?

Comment: What's in model.draw?

Comment: I'm not sure the library parses animation data from .dae files at all. If it's simple transformations, like rotating a cube, you could animate that in Processing, either timing the rotations yourself or using a library like [Ani](http://www.looksgood.de/libraries/Ani/) to handle the interpolation and timing for you

Comment: I took model.draw from an example I don't know what's in it. @laancelot

Comment: This one is just a cube but I would like to make more complex animated objects and I think it is more easier for me to work with blender and send them to Processing after that's why. I will take a look at what you suggest. Thank you. @GeorgeProfenza